# How to know whether file is completed writing by Spring batch

Tags: spring

I want to understand when and how spring batch creates and writes files. Means, files are open until batch is completed? I wanted to know whether the file is open at my destination server. What is the best way i can do that.
My application is running on Unix, jboss server

Answer (score 0):

You can check open file descriptors for the PID. You may use lsof command.

Comment: i tried. But i am not sure exactly which FD or PID to use. which process it may use